# White Lines on Jupyter Notebook stopping kernal from running cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working on a jupyter notebook at the minute and these 4 white lines have popped up which seems to kill the kernal. Manually I can run any cells after this but it won't do it automatically.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IANAm.png

I can't click into them to edit or delete them. I have no idea where they appeared from.

Hoping someone can shed some light

Answer (score 0):

I just Googled this as I have the same problem. Saving the Notebook and refreshing the browser window worked for me on a case-by-case basis.

But apparently [it's fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68994024/jupyterlab-notebook-cells-going-missing) now, so updating your Jupyter-Lab should solve the issue.